# Developing desktop applications in visual studio express for web 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Developing desktop applications in visual studio express for web is possible?I have installed visual studio express for web 2012 in my system.I have started doing my windows project in visual studio but windows templates are not available. Do i have to install visual studio express for windows to develop my project.please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Microsoft ***Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop*** for desktop application.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=34673